# SharePoint 2013 Multiple Server Configuration Guidance

Tags: sharepoint-server, administration

I looking for some installation guidance article on SharePoint 2013 multiple server for five tier farm(2 Apps Server,2 WFE,1 SQL Server).

Comment: That's a three tier farm

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805948.aspx

Comment: I am looking for 5 tier farm....

Comment: There is no such thing, what you are referring to above is a three tier farm with redundant app and web servers

Answer (score 1):

When I setup a new farm I plan ahead and make minimum use of AutoSPInstaller. Setting up service applications needed is pretty straight forward process based on you needs, but services on server is always trickier. Often I find myself installing WFE1 first and end up with Central Administration on the front end.

As you might have guessed, the CA should be present on one of the App servers. It's easely changed by New-SPCentralAdministration cmdlet, but why bother when you can make it right the first time. In order to get it right, I use the services on server spreadsheet which is a great tool to get it right the first time.

[Services on server install workseet for traditional SharePoint Server 2013 topologies](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30367)

Answer (score 0):

Link shared from the Robert is correct article to follow. Basically number of servers are not count towards tie topology, it is more about server roles i.e APp server, WFE or SQL. Here are steps, i would follow.

- create the Service Account
- Configure the permission on the Server.
- Install the SQL Server on the database server and set the permission inside the SQL.
- Now Install SharePoint on the App & WFE servers( you can follow any method[manual or scripted]).
- Install the any CU which you want or any language packs(if applicable)
- Now run the Confif wizard on the server where you want to host the Central admin.
- after this join remaining server to that farm.
- now do the test.